# Get a JSON array with HTTP Get using javascript (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-get, arrays

*I've been trying some code from here to achieve my goal but I haven't found the solution yet.*

**Goal**: I have to get a JSON objects array from a web (through the URL) using GET method. I have to do that in Javascript or HTML. I have been trying in javascript with jquery and with ajax. The idea is when the webpage I'm making loads I have to get the JSON objects array. I would want to save the JSON objets array fetched in a string to manipulate it.

Example of JSON array that I have to get from http://www.example.com/example

```
[
    {
        "type": "1",
        "id": "50a92047a88d8",
        "title": "Real Madrid"
    },
    {
        "type": "1",
        "id": "500cbb1a5ef23",
        "title": "Fernando Alonso"
    }
]
```

When I run my code in the browser I always get no response.

These are some pieces of code I've tried:

HTML Code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body onload = "httpGet('http://www.example.com/example')">
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript code

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
$.getJSON(theUrl, function(data)
{
    $.each(data, function()
    {
        console.log(this['title']);
    })
});
}
```

Other Javascript code

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: theUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    accept: 'application/json',
    success: function(data)
    {  
        console.log(data);
        var objets= $.parseJSON(data);

        $.each(objets, function(i, obj)
        {
           console.log(obj.title);
        });
    }
});
```

And I have prove a lot of code from here (stak overflow)...

Thank you very much and excuse me for my English.

Edit:

Some time ago I tried with stringify, but I don't really known how can it works.
I proved the following:

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = null;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true ); // I tried with true and with false
    xmlHttp.send();
    var answer= xmlHttp.responseText;
    var str = JSON.stringify(answer);
    console.log(str);
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(str);
    console.log(jsonResponse);
}
```

Comment: Is the specified URL pointing at _your_ domain, i.e., the same domain your page loaded from? A standard ajax request (for JSON or any other format) won't work cross-domain.

Comment: use stringify for this

Comment: So what's in `data` upon success? Does it ever hit `success`. Maybe it hits `error` instead. Did you try adding a callback for that and seeing what happens? Also, checking your Network tab in Chrome/Firefox Inspector is usually helpful for this too.

Comment: The URL is not pointing at my domain, so have I to reject using an ajax request?

Comment: Yes, I've tried using a callback function. I always see the result of executing my code with Firebug Firefox complement.

Comment: and I always see 200 OK and no response. I don't understand why I obtain a 200 OK but I don't obtain the json array.

Answer (score -1):

You can't fetch data cross domain with javascript, you have to put the data under your domain or using jsonp to get it, or just print it on the page.

Comment: I think you haven't understood me, or I haven't explained myself well, or both.
I want to save in a variable the JSON objects array retrieved with the GET call.

Comment: if the GET call address is not the same domain as your script, your call will fail, and there is no response. just check this [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/)

Comment: Then, what the hell should I do? With jsoup is possible doing this?

Comment: i am sorry, it's a typo for jsonp, it's not easy to discus jsonp in comment, you can view more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: But in the answer header I see this:
Content-Type application/json
So, if the content-type expected by the server is json, can I do the request with a dataType:'jsonp'?
If I do this I don't receive neither the 200 OK nor the answear headers.

Comment: that depends on the server, if it support jsonp, every thing is ok, otherwise you can do nothing. :(

Comment: I guess that if the answer header shows that the content-type is application/json it means that the server doesn't support jsonp, no?
Isn't there any other possible solution?

Comment: maybe you will ask server provider if they are support jsonp. there is no other way if you use **Only javascript**.

Comment: and what are other possible ways without using only javascript?

Comment: Another thing I don't understand is this: When I prove my code in chrome i get the following message "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." I don't know if this could be the problem, and I don't know how could I solve this.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin. means you are try to do a cross domain request, Chrome will add a header and ask server whether they support cross domain call. if the server recognize this header, and allow cross domain request, you will success. however not all browser will add this header. if you can do the request in backend server, there will be ok, java/php/python ext.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution to my problem with one line php code

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/example");
?>
```

After that, I needed to reference the php file in the javascript file.
Finally I could access to the key-value pairs of the JSON objects array.

```
function httpGet()
{    
    $.getJSON('phpfile.php', function(data)
    {
        $.each(data, function(i, obj) 
        {
            console.log("object: " + i + ", title: " + obj.title);
        });
    });
}
```

In the HTML file I modified the next line:

```
<body onload = "httpGet()">
```